# Type for a String that must conform to some syntax

Tags: rust, serde

I'd like to make a "constrained" type that behaves like `String`, but on construction validates that it conforms to some syntax. For example, we might create an `Identifier` type that acts like a `String` but enforces that all characters match `[a-zA-Z_]`.

In particular, I want the usual traits to be implemented (`Display`, `Ord`, etc.), and I want `serde::Serialize` and `serde::Deserialize` to behave just like with a normal `String`, except that we validate when deserializing.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this, or would I have to implement all the traits manually?

Comment: Do you want to check it during run-time or compile-time?

Comment: *but on construction* — so it's acceptable for the type to no longer conform to the constraints **after** construction? *behaves like `String`* —  In which **exact** manners? Should you be able to convert it into an iterator of `chars`? What about `push` a character to it? There are *a lot* of `String` behaviors to choose from.

Answer (score 5):

The idiomatic way would be to create a [newtype](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html?highlight=newtype#using-the-newtype-pattern-for-type-safety-and-abstraction) around `String` and to derive the traits that can be derived.

[For example:](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d71119771c93747d7ee95c62844a019b)

```rust
use serde;
use serde_json;

#[derive(
    Eq, PartialEq, Ord, PartialOrd,
    Debug, Default,
    serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize,
)]
#[serde(transparent)] // to serialize as a string
pub struct Identifier(
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "Identifier::deserialize")]
    String
);

impl Identifier {
    pub fn new(s: String) -> Result<Identifier, &'static str> {
        // do some validation
        if !s.is_empty() && s.contains('a') {
            Ok(Identifier(s))
        } else {
            Err("Not valid")
        }
    }

    fn deserialize<'de, D>(d: D) -> Result<String, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        use serde::de::Error;
        use serde::Deserialize;

        let s = String::deserialize(d)?;
        Identifier::new(s).map(|i| i.0).map_err(D::Error::custom)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Identifier::new("aaa".into()).unwrap();
    let b: Identifier = serde_json::from_str(r#""faaa""#).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}, {:?}", a, b);
    println!("{}", a == b);
}
```